# cast (sysdate as date) doesn't give exact integer values

Tags: oracle

Why does

```
select (cast(sysdate as date) - to_date('01011970','DDMMYYYY')) * 86400 from dual;
```

give values like 1582881272,000000000000000000000000000001 or 
1582881301,999999999999999999999999999999 instead of exact integer values?

I thought "cast(sysdate as date)" cuts the milliseconds, so * 86400 ensures integer values.

Do i really need to round (!) this?

Comment: To begin with, in Oracle DB, sysdate does not have milliseconds, it's already a DATE type, so the cast is useless. Second I just tried your query, and it does NOT give decimal number, just integer. Which tool are you using? are you sure you did not have a formatting issue with it.

Comment: same issue when inserting into a table ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the factors:

```
86400 = 24 * 60 * 60 = (2³*3)*(2*3*5)*(2*3*5) = 25*3³*5²
```

Unless your number of seconds since midnight is a multiple of 3³=27 (so you are just left with the factors of 2 and 5 in the divisor) you then are going to get recurring number that cannot be expressed nicely as a decimal so regardless of the precision that Oracle stores the result of `SYSDATE - DATE '1970-01-01'` it is going to be inaccurate to some small degree.

You will just need to round the number:

```sql
SELECT ROUND((SYSDATE - DATE '1970-01-01')* 86400) FROM DUAL;
```

However, if you are trying to create a unix timestamp then you should use:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(
         (CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE) - DATE '1970-01-01') * 86400
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

As Unix timestamps are in the UTC time zone.

Or, if you want to do it without rounding:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT( DAY FROM diff ) * 24 * 60 * 60
       + EXTRACT( HOUR FROM diff ) * 60 * 60
       + EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM diff ) * 60
       + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM diff ) AS unix_timestamp
FROM   (
  SELECT CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE)
         - TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
           AS diff
  FROM   DUAL
)
```

*(The cast is there to remove the fractional seconds that `SYSTIMESTAMP` normally has.)*

Answer (score 1):

`cast(sysdate as date)` can be simplified to `sysdate` because it **is** already a `date` value.

And in Oracle a `DATE` **always** contains a time part, there is no way to get rid of it.

The only thing you can do, is to set it to midnight using `trunc(sysdate)`

```
select (trunc(sysdate) - to_date('01011970','DDMMYYYY')) * 86400 
from dual;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a5211ebd3961dbb3232c657e3812b0c3)

Comment: "select (sysdate - to_date('01011970','DDMMYYYY')) * 86400 from dual;" gives the same decimal values.
Therefore i tried "cast ...".
"select trunc(sysdate - to_date('01011970','DDMMYYYY')) * 86400 from dual;" cuts even the hours, minutes, ...
"select trunc((sysdate - to_date('01011970','DDMMYYYY')) * 86400) from dual;" works, but that's like rounding ...

Comment: Sorry, it was copy & paste error. it must be `trunc(sysdate) - ...`

Answer (score 0):

In my system (Oracle 11.2) I see the same issue:

```
select (sysdate - date '1970-01-01') * 86400 from dual;
```

can result in 1582884027,000000000000000000000000000003 for instance. It seems Oracle uses an approximate type (float/double) for the calculation which it shouldn't.

The obvious solution:

```
select round((sysdate - date '1970-01-01') * 86400) from dual;
```

Comment: Subtracting two DATE indeed results in a `NUMBER` to cater for fractional days. That's why the time part of `sysdate` needs to be set to midnight in order to get full days.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, but as dates go only down to seconds, the difference between the two dates multiplied by 86400 (i.e. 24 * 60 * 60) should result in an integer (namely the difference in seconds).

Comment: But multiplying a fractional number with an integer still gives a fractional number `1.234 * 86400` yields `106617.6`

Comment: thanks! bit frustrating, but as i feared, rounding seems the only solution

Comment: Note, Unix timestamps are based on `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` - so you get some offsets if your database server operating system is not running on UTC times.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The precision for the data type `DATE` is seconds. So every difference between two dates is an integer number of  seconds. Expressed in days this will be a fraction `seconds/86400`. If I multiply `seconds/86400` with `86400`, I should get the integer seconds.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit: Well it's on CET, ok, but the time shift covers HOURS, not seconds or fractions of them.

Comment: Just checked with `DUMP`: `select dump(sysdate - date '1970-01-01') from dual;` returns something like `Typ=14 Len=8: 144,71,0,0,58,148,0,0`. The code 14 is not even documented (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50950) and is probably some internal approximate float type.

Comment: And I found this: https://bennytu.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/subtracting-dates-in-oracle-how-it-is-stored-internally/ explaining the result type.